# Registering method in custom SecurityExpressionOperations as Spring SpEL function

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-el

I have the following implementation of `MethodSecurityExpressionOperations`

```
public class CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot extends SecurityExpressionRoot implements MethodSecurityExpressionOperations {
        private Object filterObject;
        private Object returnObject;

        CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot(Authentication authentication) {
          super(authentication);
        }

        public boolean isTeamMember(Job job) {
          //very interesting logic
        }

        @Override
        public Object getFilterObject() {
          return this.filterObject;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getReturnObject() {
          return this.returnObject;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getThis() {
          return this;
        }

        @Override
        public void setFilterObject(Object obj) {
          this.filterObject = obj;
        }

        @Override
        public void setReturnObject(Object obj) {
          this.returnObject = obj;
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have custom defined method called `isTeamMember`. This method is successfully evaluated by the following pre authorize annotation: `@PreAuthorize("isTeamMember(#job)")` but unfortunately it is not resolved as the Spring SpEL function.

[see the warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1l8x.png)

Is there any Spring Bootish automagic way to register `isTeamMember` as SPeL function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say this is IntelliJ IDEA concern and fully unrelated to the [Function](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-ref-functions) support in SpEL:

> You can extend SpEL by registering user defined functions that can be called within the expression string.

There is nothing to do from the SpEL, Spring Framework or Spring Boot side since all you need is there already via your `CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot`.

What you have in your WARN is just a pointer that the IDEA knowledge about root Object of the SpEL evaluation context is out of your custom `CustomMethodSecurityExpressionRoot` scope.

You may do like this `#this.isTeamMember(#obj)` or `#root.isTeamMember(#obj)` to have the same result, but again: there is nothing about fucntions. Don't confuse yourself.

Answer (score 0):

hopefully with the new version of Intellij IDEA 2022.3.1 this is resolved.
just upgrade to latest version if you are using Itellij.