# @PreAuthorize Annotation cannot resolve variable

Tags: java, spring, rest, security, intellij-idea

We are using RestController and we always get a warning on every single method telling us that the variable from the @PreAuthorize annotation can not be resolved:

```java
  @GetMapping
  @PreAuthorize("isAdmin()")
  public ResponseEntity<ResponseBodyWrapper<List<ListData>>> getList() {
    // Logic
  }
```

Is there anyway to get rid of the warning?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45673908/registering-method-in-custom-securityexpressionoperations-as-spring-spel-functio

Answer (score 2):

It's not the best solution, but you can suppress the inspection for the method using `@SuppressWarnings("SpringElInspection")`. If you found a way to get `Intellij` to resolve the variable rather than suppressing the warning, i'd love to see it.

Comment: I don't want to use the @SuppressWarnings("SpringElInspection"), but thanks anyway
Unfortunatelly i haven't found one yet, but it seems that IntelliJ has changed the warning for authorizations to a green semi-transparent background, rather then the original yellow, but the cannot resolve path variable is still ther.

Comment: Yeah, it's a pick your poison situation - do you want to clutter your code with non-essential annotations or would you rather to dig through repetitive code warnings when you commit?

Answer (score 0):

The following actions solved the errors for me (IntelliJ IDE):

1. Press alt+enter hovering on the red-marked annotation (@PreAuthorize in this case) and click on 'Add Maven dependency'. The IDE will automatically add any missing dependency that might be causing errors or warnings.
2. Open a new terminal in the IDE and run the following command:

   ```
   mvn clean install -DskipTests
   ```

Comment: Unfortunatelly this still does not remove the warning from it in IntelliJ.
The only real way is to use the @SuppressWarnings("SpringElInspection")